# http://localhost doesn't work after installing apache

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

After installing Apache I tried running httpd using the following command `httpd -k start` and it gave me the following error message:

`AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::283a:e00e:3927:eef. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.`

So I changed the following section of httpd.conf:

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80   
Servername localhost
```

Now `httpd -k start` didn't give me any error but when I entered "http://localhost" on my browser, it was supposed to show me the "It Works!" page (index.html from the htdocs folder) but it didn't. Instead it was an error message saying:

```
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I then tried changing the following section of httpd.conf: `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080` and entered http://localhost:8080 on my browser but it didn't work so I changed it back. I also checked the Windows Defender firewall but Apache was allowed access to the network. Also port 80 wasn't being utilized according to `netstat -a`.

I tried the `httpd -k stop` command but it gave me the following error:

(OS 5)Access is denied.  : `AH10014: Failed to open the 'Apache2.4' service`

So I don't know if it is related so please help.

Comment: Try using just `127.0.0.1` or the local IP of the computer (e.g. something like `192.168.1.X`) rather than `localhost`.

Comment: `Servername`? `ServerName`

Comment: @Anaksunaman thanks for the suggestion, i already tried doing that and much more troubleshooting, but it did not work so i finally installed xampp instead and it worked!

Comment: @TomYan yes, sorry that was a typo here, i did write ServerName in the config file, but thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved. =)